# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert message

Tags: truffle, require

When a solidity smart contract reverts with a message due to a failure on a require statement, the browser calling the smart contract returns "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert". However, it does not show the message associated with the require statement.

I am using Truffle v5.0.1 (Solidity v0.5.0 and Node v11.6.0).

Is there a way to get this message in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revert reason strings are a new-ish addition, and a big part of the ecosystem still has no support for it. Currently, the only way to get the reason string is by using the latest versions of `ganache-cli` with the latest versions of Truffle.

I don't know if Metamask has support to display it in the browser [citation needed], but you should be able to catch it in your code and do a `console.log()`.

Comment: I updated ganache-cli also, and it now works :) Thanks

Comment: yes updating ganache really works